# JNI can't find shared library after program has been deployed

Tags: java, boost, java-native-interface, sles

I am having troubles after moving an exported Java project from the development machine to the production.

The java project (an Eclipse plugin) has a JNI library written by me, which depends on a open source library, which in turn depends on Boost. I compiled everything, including Boost, on my SLES11 machine and the program just works.

When I move the program to another machine, I get the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:/path/to/project/lib/libMyJNI.so: libboost_system.so.1.67.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I copied the needed libraries in the same directory. 
`ldd libMyJNI.so` lists 20 dependencies but solves all of them.

I still get the same error.

I assume that `java.library.path` is correctly set, because it tries to load `libMyJNI.so` and recognize the dependencies.

Am I right expecting that if `ldd` works, java should solve the dependencies?
Any clue?

Thank you!

EDIT: here's the output of ldd `ldd libMyJNI.so`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa59ff000)
libboost_system.so.1.67.0 (0x00007fc427bce000)
libboost_filesystem.so.1.67.0 (0x00007fc4279b4000)
libboost_thread.so.1.67.0 (0x00007fc42778f000)
libboost_date_time.so.1.67.0 (0x00007fc42757a000)
libboost_iostreams.so.1.67.0 (0x00007fc42735f000)
libboost_serialization.so.1.67.0 (0x00007fc42710f000)
libboost_chrono.so.1.67.0 (0x00007fc426f06000)
libboost_atomic.so.1.67.0 (0x00007fc426d04000)
libboost_regex.so.1.67.0 (0x00007fc426a00000)
libpcl_common.so.1.8 (0x00007fc42673b000)
libpcl_io.so.1.8 (0x00007fc4263cb000)
libpcl_octree.so.1.8 (0x00007fc425fdc000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc425c98000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc425a42000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc42582b000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc4254cc000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc4252c3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc4250a6000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fc424e8f000)
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007fc424c86000)
libpcl_io_ply.so.1.8 (0x00007fc424a21000)
libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fc4247f9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc427fe8000)
```

Comment: does `ldd` list boost? Probably it isn't linked after all. The linker won't complain because in Linux it's assumed that all needed libraries will be linked into the executable. Which isn't the case with a JNI library.

Comment: @user2543253 Yes, it lists some boost libs, some libs from the open source library and things like `libm.so`, `libc.so`. I don't understand completely, how could I link it?

Comment: Hm, but does it list the exact file that the error message is complaining about? Is that exact file there? Is it readable?

Comment: @user2543253 I added the output of `ldd` to the question. It lists the exact file with the same name and version. I have read permission, I don't have exec but I think it's not needed. On the machine is also installed a different version of boost, I don't know if it can be an issue

Comment: Do you run the program with a different user or with sudo so it maybe gets a different environment as `ldd`? I'm a bit confused by the `ldd` output. I've never seen it list the libraries without the `=>` and the path.

Comment: @user2543253 Yes, maybe it gets a different environment than `ldd`, I will check it. I think `ldd` omits the path when the libraries are in the same folder. I have copied the libraries (pcl and boost, the ones that I don't expect to find installed on the target machine) in the same folder of `libMyJNI.so`, so I think `ldd` just finds them there and doesn't bother to display the path.

Comment: I checked the environment variables and the java.library.path from within the plugin. In none of them the path to my libraries is mentioned, so I think differences are not relevant. Maybe there is some Eclipse internal that load the libraries from the plugin path, since the library is found and almost loaded. I really don't get how the JNI "linker" works, and how to diagnostic it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JNI linker. You say you want to load a library and Java has the OS loader load it for you. "java.library.path" also is only relevant for the actual JNI lib. The OS doesn't see it for the dependencies and won't care about it. `ld.so.conf` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are usually the only things to check. You *can* however load a non-JNI lib inside Java and the OS should find it when resolving dependencies because it will be in memory already. Maybe you could try loading the "problem" lib from inside your code and see if you get a more helpful error message.

Comment: Thank you, I solved! I moved the `.so` files (except `libMyJNI.so`) in a folder listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. `ldd` was working from terminal because it also looks in the current directory. So the dependence libraries have to be in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, not `java.library.path`. Thank you a lot again. Should I write an answer to the question?

Comment: I think it is customary to write an answer, so the question doesn't show up as unanswered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user2543253 I have solved the problem. I am giving an answer for readers in the future (including me, when I will have the same problem).

`java.library.path` was correctly set, because it could load the JNI library. The other libraries (the dependencies) have to be in a directory listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So when deploying the software, you can either

- install the dependencies in places normally present in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or
- append a directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before starting the plugin.

`ldd` could be successful in linking the library because it also looks in the current directory. So `ldd libMyJNI.so` could succeed while `ldd \path\to\libMyJNI.so` may fail. In this case, JNI won't work.